# Can I hide the file extensions in an SWT FileDialog filter?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an SWT FileDialog (style: SWT.OPEN) with multiple filters each with multiple file extensions. I want to include an "All known formats" filter with every file extension the application recognizes. This list is very long and will not fit on-screen. On Mac, the FileDialog sizes the filter combo box the width of the widest filter string. The control is not easily usable because the string is too wide to fit on-screen and the text is centered so you cannot read the filter description at the beginning.

Can I hide the file extensions in the FileDialog filter combo box drawn on-screen but still associate the extensions with the filter? Does anyone have alternate suggestions?

**Screenshots of problem**

[image: All known formats filter on Mac]
[image: Available filters for files recognized by the application]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @iberbeu, I'm sorry but I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: @Baz, the top image shows the combo box truncation and the bottom image shows the multiple filters with their multiple file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileDialog requires that you provide a list of descriptions and a list of extensions to define a set of filters. I overlooked the fact that my code concatenated the descriptor and the extension list to make a more descriptive label. This was done at a time when the number of supported file types was small. The answer is to provide a condition where the extension list is not appended to the description "All known formats." That's embarrassing...

Thank you to those who responded.